# emacs regex with multiple match for text, in multi line buffer

Tags: regular-expressions

Following is sample text.

```
Header
This is test, and
mid line adsf
bag a lot of many things
shoes>
shoes/
This line should not be affected.
Neither this line.
This is test, and
mid line
bag a lot of many things
shoes>
shoes/
Footer
```

Need to replace/remove lines where text starts with `This is test` and ends with

```
shoes>
shoes/
```

using Emacs 26.1

Newbie to RegEx (emacs), following were my trials, failed to select multiple instance.

```
(This is test).*(shoes/)
^This is test.*shoes/$
```

Expected output is

```
Header
This line should not be affected.
Neither this line.
Footer
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the following regexp

```
This is test\(.*\n\)+?shoes>\nshoes/\n
```

- `.*\n` matches a line
- `+?` matches multiple lines in non-greedy way

---

Using the regexp in `C-M-s` (`isearch-forward-regexp`):

[image]

Note: to enter `\n` in the minibuffer of Isearch, use `C-q C-j`. As you can see, Isearch renders it as something like `^J`.

When the matching is expected, to delete the matched text, type `M-%` (`isearch-query-replace`) to switch to Query-Replace, and type `RET` to supply an empty replacement, then type `!` to replace all matches. In the end, you will get:

[image]